# Regex groups and complements

Tags: group-theory, regular-language, regular-expressions

Not sure about the "math" language of that but ill try to explain my question:
Assume we have two regexes `A, B`. I say Regex `A` is a "full subset" of `B` if every input that matches `A` will also matches `B`.
Small example, `A= a.* B=.*`
Every input in A will also match in B. So `A ⊆ B`

Now my question is, how this relates to the complements groups? Say the complements of `A` and `B` are `~A` and `~B`. Does `~A ⊆ ~B`? what about `~A` and `B` or `A` and `~B`?

I mean by complement is the group that contains all the input that dont match `A`

And what if `A` is not a full subset of `B`? Can we say anything about the compliments?

Thanks!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: But how is that  a group? What is the group operation?